# How to add PostgreSQL in Java with Maven?

Tags: java, database, postgresql, maven

I want to make an application where it uses PostgreSQL in Java using Maven. The problem appears when, adding to the dependency PostgreSQL, I cannot use the SQL's classes, although in pom.xml be the dependency.

Here's the pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.hah</groupId>
    <artifactId>EjemploSimplePersonas</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.4.0</version>
            <type>xml</type>
            <classifier>features</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.hah.ejemplosimplepersonas.Ejecutable</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for manual attach debugging -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run@debug -->
                        <id>debug</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=localhost:8000</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for automatic IDE debugging -->
                        <id>ide-debug</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address}</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for automatic IDE profiling -->
                        <id>ide-profile</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg1}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg2}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg3}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg4}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg5}</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            
            <!-- Copia las dependencias librerias javafx .jar a la carpeta "lib" de tu proyecto -->
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
        <excludeTransitive>false</excludeTransitive> 
        <stripVersion>false</stripVersion>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    </plugin>
    
    <!-- Agrega la referencia del contenido de la carpeta "lib" en el classpath de tu proyecto-->
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                <mainClass>com.hah.ejemplosimplepersonas.Ejecutable</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
    </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And this is the problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBPw5.jpg

Note: I tried to use postgresl as org.postgresql when I added dependencies in Maven, nothing worked.

Note 2: I downloaded the version "postresql:postgresql" and "org.postgresql:postgresql".

Edit: I created using NetBeans, with this specifications: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsRba.jpg

The stranger thing, is that it works perfectly when I create using the simple specification, I mean, whith this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1cjU.jpg
It's strange that it works with any problem in simple specification, but no when the other way.

Comment: Maybe you should just remove the <type>xml</type> and <classifier>features</classifier>. Where have you got that from?

Comment: I don't have that lines, sorry, I'm new using this tools.

Comment: It's in your pom.xml where you declare the dependency on PostgreSQL. Just search with your editor.

Comment: Answering your question, Maven adds that by default when I add it by "add library". Also I already tried your recommendation to remove those elements, and there is no change, I still can't use sql libraries...

Comment: What I understand is you are trying to use Postgres driver. Remove the 'type' and 'classifier' element as suggested above. import org.postgresql.Driver and create an instance of the driver and register with DriverManager. Your GAV for Postgres is correct. if you want to add the JAR manually add 'postgresql-42.4.0.jar' to the classpath.

Comment: The missing "Connection" interface is a standard java JDBC interface. You probably also have to add the module "java.sql" to your modules.

Comment: Excuse me, could you be more specific? I am new to this and I don't know how to proceed with the instructions you are telling me

Answer (score 0):

I think I was able to solve it based on what has been explained to me.
Once the postgresql dependency has been downloaded, we proceed to add said library in the `module-info.java` class, so that in this way the libraries downloaded from the dependencies in Maven can be used.
It is possible to get confused because it is customary to use SQL classes from Java, but since you are using Maven, you have to import them from there (that is why it is important to show the Path):
[Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ou6A.png)

And this is how the code looked in `module-info.java`:

```
module com.proyecto.zzzeliminar {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires org.postgresql.jdbc;
    opens com.proyecto.zzzeliminar to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.proyecto.zzzeliminar;
}
```

With that we can use the classes to connect and interact with the data base.
[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D32tH.png)

Comment: This is not fully correct because you now have an explicit dependency on PostgreSQL in your code. If you add java.sql to your module-info.java you can use Connection as before.

Comment: And how could I do that?

Comment: Oh, I got it. Write `requires java.sql` in `module-info.java`. You are right, I proved and it works, thank you so much :)